# Numpy Python - Inserting a Matrix at a list of indexes of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to insert multiple columns at multiple indexes of a Numpy Matrix.

So far, I have the code below:

```
MatrixA = np.zeros(shape=(200,300))
MatrixB = np.ones(shape=(200,1))
index_list = [1,3,5]
Output = np.insert(MatrixA, index_list, MatrixB, axis=1)
```

And it returns an output similar to what I'm looking for:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 1., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

However, this is just for a single column. When I try to add in multiple columns:

```
MatrixA = np.zeros(shape=(200,300))
MatrixB = np.ones(shape=(200,2))
index_list = [1,3,5]
Output = np.insert(MatrixA, index_list, MatrixB, axis=1)
```

I get an error:

**ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (200,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,200)**

My desired output would be something like:

```
array([[0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Does anyone know how to do this and why I'm getting the error above?

Comment: `MatrixB` has the wrong shape to go in the spaced defined by the index_list.  The error tells you the right target shape.

Comment: Is there a reason why the shape is incorrect? Does Numpy.insert only work for 1d arrays?

Comment: Is (200,2) the same as (3,200)?

Comment: I would like to add two columns at each specific index. Hence, the (200,2) shape to be inserted within (200,300). I would expect that for each element in index list, the final shape would be increased by 2. Why would it require a (3,200) input shape? How would that fit into my original Matrix?

Comment: You want `insert` to loop over columns, insert `MatrixB` after 1, then after 3+offset, and again after 5+offset.  That's not what `insert` does.  The insertion space is determined by the indices, not the size or shape of the fill value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.insert` docs say:

```
values : array_like
    Values to insert into `arr`. If the type of `values` is different
    from that of `arr`, `values` is converted to the type of `arr`.
    `values` should be shaped so that ``arr[...,obj,...] = values``
    is legal.
```

Your `MatrixA` is (200,300); indexing on axis 1 with [1,3,5]

```
 MatrixA[:,[1,3,5]]
```

has shape (200,3). (I'm not quite sure why the error message says `indexing result of shape (3,200)`.)

Let's illustrate with smaller arrays:

```
In [328]: MatrixA = np.zeros(shape=(2,10))                                                     
In [329]: MatrixB = np.ones(shape=(2,2))                                                       
In [330]: index_list = [1,3,5]                                                                 
In [331]: Output = np.insert(MatrixA, index_list, 1, axis=1)                                   
In [332]: Output.shape                                                                         
Out[332]: (2, 13)
In [333]: Output                                                                               
Out[333]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [334]: Output[:,[1,4,7]]                                                                    
Out[334]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

`insert` has, in effect, opened up `MatrixA` after columns 1,3,5, and inserted the fill value.  The space it opens up is determined by the `index_list`, **not** by the size of the fill value.  It is not inserting the fill at each column, but rather trying to insert it into the whole fill space:

```
In [337]: Output = np.insert(MatrixA, index_list, np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3), axis=1)         
In [338]: Output                                                                               
Out[338]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 4., 0., 0., 5., 0., 0., 6., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

To insert 2 values at each slot, we need to duplicate the indices:

```
In [339]: Output = np.insert(MatrixA, [1,1,3,3,5,5], 2, axis=1)                                
In [340]: Output.shape                                                                         
Out[340]: (2, 16)
In [341]: Output                                                                               
Out[341]: 
array([[0., 2., 2., 0., 0., 2., 2., 0., 0., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 2., 0., 0., 2., 2., 0., 0., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

`np.repeat(index_list,2)` does that duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a 2d array, but you need to use a `slice` object.
I couldn't manage to pass multiple slices at once to `np.insert`, therefore if it is not too computational demanding you can do a for loop, namely:

```
slices = [slice(i, i+MatrixB.shape[1]) for i in index_list]

for s in slices:
     MatrixA[:,s] = MatrixB
```

Remark that this is **not** equivalent to `np.insert`, since it will not add dimension to `MatrixA`. After the computation, `MatrixA.shape` is still `(200,300)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it gave me an idea :).


I am still interested to see if this is possible in a native numpy method for efficiency purposes.

Comment: `np.insert` is python code, not compiled.  Look at it.